# ifthenelse doesn't work in case of string comparison

Tags: conditionals, lastpage

I tried to use this code to place footer in all pages except the last page in which I just want an "end".

```
\ifthenelse
    {\equal
        {\detokenize{\thepage}}
        {\detokenize{\pageref{LastPage}}}
    }
    {
        \rfoot[]{\textit{End}}
    }
    {
        \rfoot[]{\textit{Continued on next page :: \curpage :: \mylastpage}}
    }
```

However, this prints `Continued on next page...` in all pages including the last page. I have tried without `detokenize` as well, but it doesn't work. Tried other ifs like pdfstrcmp, that also fails.
Why does this comparison not work?

Comment: Please add some code to make this example working (at least compiling)

Comment: with `\detokenize` you are comparing essentially `thepage` against `pageref{LastPage}` which are not equal strings, and without it you are comparing the expansion of `\thepage` which is the print form of the page number (not necessarily the number that this text will appear on) against the expansion of `\pageref` which could be all sorts of things including an error. `\pageref` does not work by expansion, and has different behaviour on thw first run when the ref is not known, or if hyperref is being used, when it makes a link, none of these will be `\ifx` equal to the expansion of `\thepage`

Comment: why not simply use `\thispagestyle{empty}` before `\end{document}` so the last page has an empty foot?

Comment: I've added another approach, which does not use the non-working `\detokenize` which is of no use here due to wrong concept of comparison partially non-expanding commands

Comment: Ok, I just have seen that David Carlisle provided a far more elaborate comment ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I am pretty new to `tex`, so writing silly rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `\detokenize{\pageref{LastPage}}` is surely not what you want, but even `\pageref{LastPage}` wouldn't work, because it doesn't produce a number, but the instructions to print a number.

Using `zref-lastpage` is the safest method I know.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{zref-lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\LastPageNumber}{\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{page}{0}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% clear all fields

\fancyfoot[R]{%
  \ifnum\value{page}<\LastPageNumber
     \textit{Continued on next page :: \thepage\ :: \LastPageNumber}%
  \else
     \textit{End}%
  \fi
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{First}

\blindtext
\section{Second}
\blindtext[15]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I recognize some parts of the code, especially the ones in the lower half ;-)

Comment: I took the liberty of using your text. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried to use the zref package as well but it didn't work. Your explanation clears things out that we need to get the actual `value` of the last page.

Answer (score 3):

This provides another way of achieving the requested feature (if I have understood the question correctly)

The `totcount` and `assoccnt` packages work together to get the counter value of the total number of pages, which can be used in `\ifnumless` comparison by `etoolbox` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{assoccnt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtotcounter{totalpages}
\setcounter{totalpages}{1}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}

\rfoot[]{%
  \ifnumless{\number\value{page}}{%
    \number\totvalue{totalpages}
  }{
   \textit{Continued on next page :: \thepage :: \number\totvalue{totalpages}}
 }{%
   \textit{End}%
 }%
}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{First}

\blindtext
\section{Second}%
\blindtext[15]

\end{document}
```